# Vuejs Typescript class component refs.focus not working

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-class-components

I am using Typescript Class component and I have this problem I can't use `this.$refs.<refname>.focus()`

Template Code:

```
 <header class="py-2 px-1 m-0 row">
    <input
      type="text"
      class="form-control m-1"
      ref="searchBoard"
      placeholder="Find boards by name..."
    />
  </header>
```

This input field is inside a **popup**.

Typescript Code:

```
import { Component, Vue } from "vue-property-decorator";

@Component
export default class BoardList extends Vue {

  // I added this to solve the compile error
  $refs!: {
    searchBoard: HTMLInputElement;
  };

  isShown = false;

  toggleDropdown() {
    this.isShown = !this.isShown;
    this.$refs.searchBoard.focus();
  }
}
```

**Then I get this Error:**

[image]

this problem is **fixed** in this question [Vuejs typescript this.$refs..value does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46505813/vuejs-typescript-this-refs-reffield-value-does-not-exist)
 added:

```
  $refs!: {
    searchBoard: HTMLInputElement;
  };
```

I get a **New Error** in my console

```
[Vue warn]: Error in v-on handler: "TypeError: this.$refs.searchBoard is undefined"

found in

---> <BoardList> at src/components/boards/buttons/BoardList.vue
       <NavbarTop> at src/components/NavbarTop.vue
         <ComponentName> at src/App.vue
           <Root> vue.runtime.esm.js:619
    VueJS
```

7

is there a way to do this?

Comment: The HTMLFormElement does not have a focus method. It should be typed as HTMLInputElement instead.

Comment: yes I updated it with HTMLInputElement, but I still get the error in console. > "TypeError: this.$refs.searchBoard is undefined"

Comment: Refs are non-reactive. Are you sure that the element is not conditionally rendered (e.g. found within an element with a `v-if` directive), and that it is definitely available when the method `toggleDropdown` is invoked? What happens if you log `this.$refs` to the console?

Comment: when I console its now showing the elements and its attributes. but the focus() is not working

Comment: its working now I added the .focus() inside a setTimeout(). it's wierd

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Regarding the use of `setTimeout`:**

Based on the timing of your code, it seems your `isShown` property controls whether or not the `$refs.searchBoard` is rendered in the DOM. Instead of `setTimeout`, Vue recommends using [`$nextTick`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-nextTick) to defer an action until the next DOM cycle:

```js
toggleDropdown() {
  this.isShown = !this.isShown
  this.$nextTick(() => this.$refs.searchBoard.focus())
}
```

**Regarding `$refs`:**

A slightly cleaner alternative to the [`$refs` type extension](https://class-component.vuejs.org/guide/refs-type-extension.html) in your class is to use [`@Ref`](https://github.com/kaorun343/vue-property-decorator#-refrefkey-string-decorator):

```js
@Component
export default class BoardList extends Vue {
  @Ref() readonly searchBoard!: HTMLInputElement

  toggleDropdown() {
    this.isShown = !this.isShown
    this.$nextTick(() => this.searchBoard.focus())
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this looks good but  @Ref is giving VSCode error "'Ref' is not defined."

Comment: Import it beforehand: `import { Ref } from 'vue-property-decorator'`

Answer (score 1):

I was able to make it work, I added `.focus()` inside `setTimeout()`.

```
  toggleDropdown() {
    this.isShown = !this.isShown;

    setTimeout(() => {
      this.$refs.searchBoard.focus();
    }, 50);
  }
```

Comment: I've tried this and still returns error "Uncaught TypeError: _this2.$refs.specie.focus is not a function
    at eval"

Comment: This works for me in my inertia vue3 project. But it feels wrong. My console log in my onMount is undefined. Can anyone explain why we have to do a timeout?

Comment: @Nick The `this.isShown` if truthy will renders a new element on the DOM; we use `setTimeout()` to delay 'focus()' until the element has rendered on the DOM.

I do advise using `$nextTick()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
toggleDropdown() {
    this.isShown = !this.isShown;
    this.$refs.searchBoard.$el.focus();
}
```

Comment: Please elaborate on the answer, so that OP understands WHY you think your solution is correct.