# give highlights when item row table checked checkbox in vuejs

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, element-ui

I used code from vue typescript admin and element-ui, and will use attribute `highlight-current-row` after i check checkbox item table. when code `highlight-current-row` add attribute table, work in single select. but when add in multiple select on checkbox, it's not function

how to give highlights after check checkbox in row item table in vueJS?
I didn't find it in the library

https://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/table#single-select

https://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/table#multiple-select

thanks before

Comment: If I rightly understood your problem, you want to highlight multiple rows ?

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely right

Comment: @BTL. element-ui does not include multiple row highlights.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the : `row-class-name` together with the reference to the table to see witch items are selected.

```
<el-table :data="tableData" style="width: 100%" :row-class-name="rowClassName" ref="tab">
    <el-table-column  type="selection"  width="55"></el-table-column>
    <el-table-column prop="date" label="date" width="120"></el-table-column>
    <el-table-column prop="name" label="name" width="120"></el-table-column>
    <el-table-column prop="address" label="address"></el-table-column>
  </el-table>
```

JS:

```
data() {
  return {
    tableData: [
        { id: 1, date: '2020-07-01', name: 'Bob', address: 'Florida' }, 
        { id: 2, date: '2020-05-04', name: 'Alice', address: 'Arizona' }, 
        { id: 3, date: '2020-08-01', name: 'Carole', address: 'Calefornia' }]
  }
}
methods: {
  rowClassName({row, rowIndex}) {
    return this.$refs.tab.selection.find(element => element.id == row.id)
      ? 'selected-row'
      : ''
    }
  }
```

https://codepen.io/reijnemans/pen/dyYeBGG

Comment: why my selection in refs table does not exist @dreijntjens ?
[image](https://imgur.com/gallery/FSKaZVo)

Comment: Did you add the ref attribute to the el-table tag?

Comment: yes I added the ref attribute in the el-table tag
[image](https://imgur.com/gallery/z7gxnRr)

Comment: This related that you are using typescript, maybe you can have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46505813/vuejs-typescript-this-refs-reffield-value-does-not-exist

Comment: it's work for me...
    `return (<this>this.$refs.tab).selection.find(element => element.id == row.id)`
thanks @dreijntjens

Answer (score 1):

Here is a codepen who does exactly what you want : https://codepen.io/Andugal/pen/oNjqGWN

It uses `:row-class-name` from [Table with status](https://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/table#table-with-status) in the element-ui doc. And listen to the `select` event.

Comment: Thanks @BTL, its running in my code, but select all not work when I want to check all of the fields. how do I apply **objects** to the `select all` checkbox field?
because, in your sample codepen, just use objected, not selected
[image](https://imgur.com/gallery/pbFnoH0)