# $refs define types within component definition

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vuejs3

Let's say I have the below class:

```html
<template>
  <MyCmp ref="myForm" @click="onClickButton" />
</template>

<script>
import { defineComponent } from "vue";
import MyCmp from "@/MyCmp.vue";

export default defineComponent({
  name: "App",
  components: {
    MyCmp,
  },
  methods: {
    onClickButton() {
      // This works, but how can I define this type within this class, so I'm not having to cast it all the time?
      const myForm = this.$refs.myForm as typeof MyCmp;
      console.log(myForm);
    },
  },
});
</script>
```

I would like to be able to define the types on `$refs` instead of having to cast the type whenever I use it.  I saw [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49332129/1253609), but that doesn't seem to work for me, and I'm thinking it's Vue2 syntax.  I couldn't find anything on the official docs for this scenario, so is there a way to do this in Vue3?

Comment: You could type it like `as ComponentInternalInstance | Element | null` , `ComponentInternalInstance` should be imported from vue

Comment: `ComponentInternalInstance` doesn't work if I'm trying to access `this.$refs.myForm.$el`.

Comment: Is the Composition API out of the question? The old `$refs` become like any other `Ref` object in the new way, and can be typed like, e.g., `const myForm = ref<MyCmp>();`

Comment: @kdau, no, it's not out of the question, but I guess I was hoping for something with component definitions... similar to how props can be typed.