# How to convert $refs field to its component type in Vue 2 & TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm migrating my Vue 2.x project from JavaScript to TypeScript. Due to some historical reasons, I have no chance to use Class Style Vue Component, so I am using the `Vue.extend` way.

Here's my `ValidPeriod.vue` (omit some code for simplicity):

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <div>Some content...</div>
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import Vue from 'vue';

export default Vue.extend({
  data() {
    return {};
  },
  methods: {
    isValidate() {
      return false;
    },
  },
});
</script>
```

And now I am migrating `App.vue` which is using `ValidPeriod.vue`:

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <ValidPeriod ref="validPeriod" />
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import Vue from 'vue';
import ValidPeriod from './ValidPeriod.vue';

export default Vue.extend({
  components: {
    ValidPeriod,
  },
  data() {
    return {};
  },
  mounted() {
    validPeriod.isValidate();
  },
});
```

Now I get TS error:

> TS2339: Property 'isValidate' does not exist on type 'Vue | Element | Vue[] | Element[]'.   Property 'isValidate' does not exist on type 'Vue'.

Then I try casting it:

```js
(this.$refs.validPeriod as ValidPeriod).isValidate();
```

Now I get:

> TS2749: 'ValidPeriod' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here. Did you mean 'typeof ValidPeriod'?

Ok, so I add the `typeof`, and get:

> TS2352: Conversion of type 'Vue | Element | Vue[] | Element[]' to type 'ExtendedVue<Vue, { validPeriod: string; validPeriodStart: number | Moment; validPeriodEnd: number | Moment; error: boolean; placeholder: string[]; defaultValue: Moment[]; }, { ...; }, unknown, { ...; }>' may be a mistake because neither type sufficiently overlaps with the other. If this was intentional, convert the expression to 'unknown' first.   Type 'Element[]' is missing the following properties from type 'VueConstructor<{ validPeriod: string; validPeriodStart: number | Moment; validPeriodEnd: number | Moment; error: boolean; placeholder: string[]; defaultValue: Moment[]; } & { ...; } & { ...; } & Vue>': extend, nextTick, set, delete, and 10 more.

So my question is how can I derive some type from the `ExtendedVue<Vue, { ... }`, so that the fields defined in `ValidPeriod.vue` can be recognized?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Vuejs typescript this.$refs.<refField>.value does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46505813/vuejs-typescript-this-refs-reffield-value-does-not-exist)

Answer (score 0):

For starters, to get this working, try

```
(this.$refs.validPeriod as any).isValidate();
```

Next, you might try to import a type directly from the module.  Perhaps that resolves the issue.

```
import type ValidPeriod from './ValidPeriod.vue';
```