# Object is of type ‘unknown’ [vuejs][typescript]

Tags: typescript, vuejs3

I’m using Typescript. I have a form with inputs. I want to send these inputs in my axios request. The request is working but I have errors in my vuejs console under each variable this.$refs.: **Object is of type 'unknown’**

How to solve this error ? Is because I didn’t define type for this.$refs ?

My code:

```
export default class FormPage extends Vue {
    sendTradeRequest() {
        const object = {
            coinbase:{
                key: this.$refs.coinbase.key,
                secret: this.$refs.coinbase.secret
            },
            coinbase_pro:{
                key: this.$refs.coinbase_pro.key,
                secret: this.$refs.coinbase_pro.secret,
                passphrase: this.$refs.coinbase_pro.passphrase
            }   
        };
        axios.post('/get_trade', object).then(response => { //this.$refs
          console.log(response.data);
        })
    }
 }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46505813/vuejs-typescript-this-refs-reffield-value-does-not-exist

Comment: Thank you, resolve with:  $refs!: {
     coinbase: HTMLFormElement,
     coinbase_pro: HTMLFormElement
   }